# How to scrape in Ruby when the page elements keep changing and shifting.

Tags: html, css, ruby, web-scraping, element

I'm writing a program to download the images from an imgur album: I had just begun to write the actual image-link-code:

```
#The imports.
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = ARGV[0]

#The title.
open(url) do |f|
  $doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
  title = $doc.at_css('title').text.strip.clone
  re = /\/[a]\/\w{5}/
  s2 = url.match re
  puts title
  puts s2
end



href = $doc.xpath("//img")
puts href
```

When I ran into a major problem: the page I download isn't the page source.

For example: This album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3swCc.jpg has the following code for it's images:

`<span class="post-grid-image pointer" data-href="//i.imgur.com/zh6I7k2.png" data-title="" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1); z-index: 0; background-image: url(&quot;//i.imgur.com/zh6I7k2b.jpg&quot;);"></span>`

And yet when I look in the page source, or run the code for span elements, all the images are missing:

```
            <div class="post-images is-owner">









            <div class="post-action nodisplay"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The HTML is active, and changes based on how my browser is. There aren't any images in the page source, and everything's loaded using some weird java system. How can I scrape active elements, when there aren't even any active elements to scrape?

And what's the difference between `inspect` and 'view-source'? That's what started this whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dynamic HTML. Mechanize and/or Nokogiri can't help you unless you can build the final version of the page then pass it to them.

Instead you have to use something that can interpret JavaScript and apply CSS, such as a browser. The WATIR project would be the first thing to investigate. "inspect" and "view-source" both reflect the page after the browser has processed the JavaScript and CSS in it, which often has little bearing on what the actual page looked like prior to that. Search SO for `[ruby] [watir]`.

Use `wget`, `curl` or `nokogiri` to retrieve the page so you can see the raw HTML.

`$doc.at_css('title')` should be using the `title` method: `doc.title`.

Don't use a global like `$doc`. Learn about variable scoping then decide if a global is the right way to go.

Instead of `open` with a block:

```
open(url) do |f|
  $doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
  title = $doc.at_css('title').text.strip.clone
  re = /\/[a]\/\w{5}/
  s2 = url.match re
  puts title
  puts s2
end
```

Do this instead:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
title = doc.title
```

When working with URIs/URLs, use the built-in URI class since it's a well debugged tool:

```
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://imgur.com/a/tGRvr/layout/grid')

url.path # => "/a/tGRvr/layout/grid"
  .split('/') # => ["", "a", "tGRvr", "layout", "grid"]
```

Knowing that, you can do:

```
url.path.split('/')[2] # => "tGRvr"
```

Comment: Thanks. One problem though: The url won't always be `http://imgur.com/a/tGRvr/layout/grid`, there are many urls that I could get and put in, that's what the regex is for.

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide that information when you ask not after answers appear; Doing it after we've answered wastes our time. That said, the use of URI is still the best route. Whatever the `path` returns will be something you have to accommodate for in your code. Maintaining a regex can be a lot worse than adding a tiny bit of code to extract the third, or second, or whatever, based on the host or some other piece of information.

Comment: You don't need to be that aggressive, I wasn't trying to attack you. Besides, I need to learn regex anyway.

Comment: Nobody is being aggressive. I'm trying to make sure that the question asked meets the guidelines, and helps others who are looking for a solution, not just answer your question. SO is an online reference, so questions need to have the information in a central place, namely the text of the question, along with all necessary information, so everyone benefits.